# Having trouble creating Parent-Child Relationship in ElasticSearch 6

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm currently working through an ElasticSearch course on Udemy, but the video is talking about ElasticSearch 5 and I am currently using ElasticSearch 6. I'm having trouble translating the parent/child relationships in to the new format.

In the video is setting up `Franchise` with `Films` (i.e. `Star Wars` and `The Jedi Returns` respectively.

The tutor does the following:

```js
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPUT "127.0.0.1:9200/series" -d '
{
    "mappings": {
        "franchise": {},
        "film": {
            "_parent": {
                "type": "franchise"
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

---

However when I try adding the mappings I get the following errors:

```js
➜  Downloads curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPUT "127.0.0.1:9200/series?pretty" -d '
{
    "mappings": {
        "franchise": {},
        "film": {
            "_parent": {
                "type": "franchise"
            }
        }
    }
}'
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "Rejecting mapping update to [series] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [franchise, film]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "Rejecting mapping update to [series] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [franchise, film]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

I have tried a number of things based on the following resources but have not been able to find a soluton:
https://www.elastic.co/blog/index-type-parent-child-join-now-future-in-elasticsearch
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/parent-join.html
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/20257

**TLDR:** Can someone please help me translate a parent-child relationship from ElastiSearch 5 to the correct way of doing it in ElasticSearch 6?

---

Next step (Validation): As a validation to see if the mapping is working, the tutor then did the following:

He gets the following JSON data:

wget http://media.sundog-soft.com/es/series.json

Extract from JSON file:

```
{ "create" : { "_index" : "series", "_type" : "franchise", "_id" : "1"} }
{ "id": "1", "title" : "Star Wars" }
{ "create" : { "_index" : "series", "_type" : "film", "_id" : "260", "parent" : "1" } }
{ "id": "260", "title" : "Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope", "year":"1977" , "genre":["Action", "Adventure", "Sci-Fi"] }
```

And bulk imports data by doing the following:

```js
➜  curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPUT "127.0.0.1:9200/_bulk?pretty" --data-binary @series.json
```

Comment: Have you defined and initialize the index with your mapping before you bulk import your data? If not, give it a try.

Comment: Sorry, I think my post might be a bit misleading. The problem happens when I try doing the mapping. That's what I needed help with. So until the horizontal line break I'm explaining what the tutor does, and below is the error I get when I try doing the mappings (I don't get as far as the bulk upload - I will remove it from my post).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With Elasticsearch 6.0, there are some fundamental changes which prevent parent/child relationships.

1. One index cannot contain more than one type. Read more [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.x/removal-of-types.html).
2. Parent/child relationships have been removed, and hence the
   `_parent` field is also removed. You have to use join field instead
   of parent/child.

Parent/child relationships required that there were two distinct types and both types were defined in the same index. Now that you can't have multiple types in one index, there is no way parent/child relationships can be supported in the same way that they were supported in 5.x and prior releases.

You can refer to the join field documentation to see how to do similar things to parent/child relationships. But now, you have to define both kinds of documents within a single Elasticsearch index, within the same type. Please see the example which explains how to model "1 to many" kind of relationships (1 question, multiple answers related to that question) using a join field [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/parent-join.html).

EDIT:

The example, updated for Elasticsearch 6.x with the use of `join field` would look as follows.

Drop your existing index if it exists.

```
curl -XDELETE "http://localhost:9200/series"
```

Create new index with join field, that establishes join relationship between **franchise** & **film**:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/series" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "join_field": { 
          "type": "join",
          "relations": {
            "franchise": "film" 
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

The updated series.json from your example to be sent as an inline bulk request:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/_bulk" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{ "create" : { "_index" : "series", "_type" : "doc", "_id" : "1"} }
{ "id": "1", "title" : "Star Wars", "join_field": "franchise" }
{ "create" : { "_index" : "series", "_type" : "doc", "_id" : "260", "routing" : "1" } }
{ "id": "260", "title" : "Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope", "year":"1977" , "genre":["Action", "Adventure", "Sci-Fi"], "join_field": {"name": "film", "parent": "1"} }
{ "create" : { "_index" : "series", "_type" : "doc", "_id" : "1196", "routing" : "1" } }
{ "id": "1196", "title" : "Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back", "year":"1980" , "genre":["Action", "Adventure", "Sci-Fi"], "join_field": {"name": "film", "parent": "1"} }
{ "create" : { "_index" : "series", "_type" : "doc", "_id" : "1210", "routing" : "1" } }
{ "id": "1210", "title" : "Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi", "year":"1983" , "genre":["Action", "Adventure", "Sci-Fi"], "join_field": {"name": "film", "parent": "1"} }
{ "create" : { "_index" : "series", "_type" : "doc", "_id" : "2628", "routing" : "1" } }
{ "id": "2628", "title" : "Star Wars: Episode I - The Phantom Menace", "year":"1999" , "genre":["Action", "Adventure", "Sci-Fi"], "join_field": {"name": "film", "parent": "1"} }
{ "create" : { "_index" : "series", "_type" : "doc", "_id" : "5378", "routing" : "1" } }
{ "id": "5378", "title" : "Star Wars: Episode II - Attack of the Clones", "year":"2002" , "genre":["Action", "Adventure", "Sci-Fi", "IMAX"], "join_field": {"name": "film", "parent": "1"} }
{ "create" : { "_index" : "series", "_type" : "doc", "_id" : "33493", "routing" : "1" } }
{ "id": "33493", "title" : "Star Wars: Episode III - Revenge of the Sith", "year":"2005" , "genre":["Action", "Adventure", "Sci-Fi"], "join_field": {"name": "film", "parent": "1"} }
{ "create" : { "_index" : "series", "_type" : "doc", "_id" : "122886", "routing" : "1" } }
{ "id": "122886", "title" : "Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens", "year":"2015" , "genre":["Action", "Adventure", "Fantasy", "Sci-Fi", "IMAX"], "join_field": {"name": "film", "parent": "1"} }
'
```

The bulk request above creates one franchise and multiple films that are related with that franchise.

To query all films that have the franchise id = 1, use the following parent id query.

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/series/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "parent_id": { 
      "type": "film",
      "id": "1"
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah, I had found that info and tried quite a few things, but ultimately couldn't get it to work. Was kind of hoping someone could help me with exact syntax :/

Comment: What are the mappings of the two types in question?

Comment: Sorry if I'm not making sense. I'm very new to ElasticSearch, but all he did for the mappings was what I had pasted above, and i think everything else may be inferred from the JSON file i liked to above which looks something like this: `{ "create" : { "_index" : "series", "_type" : "franchise", "_id" : "1"} }
{ "id": "1", "title" : "Star Wars" }`

Comment: Hi, I have converted the example to run on 6.0. the series.json that was found in the link has been updated (only minor updates), for 6.0 we have to use "routing": "1" instead of "parent": "1" etc. in all statements of series.json

Comment: Wow! You are a legend! I had tried so many ways and couldn't get it! Thank you very much!!

Comment: Just to clarify some parts which are unclear also in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/parent-join.html)... the `routing` value for the child document must be set to be equal to the parent id ! unfortunately all the examples are with `routing: "1"` which is not a binary switch.
I found [this](http://kimjmin.net/2018/01/2018-01-parent-child-to-join/) blog post very helpful.
And btw, the second line in the *series.json* for the parent document can also be `{ "id": "1", "title" : "Star Wars", "join_field": {"name": "franchise"} }`

Answer (score 1):

In completion of what @Pranav Shukla said if you want to query the franchise that a given film belongs to it (e.g. "The Force Awakens"), you can use the following query:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/series/_search?pretty -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '    
{                                          
  "query": {
    "has_child" : {
      "type": "film",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "title": "The Force Awakens"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```